# What can be done to make this question more constructive?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, reopen-closed

The [What's the best way to define a class in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387707/whats-the-best-way-to-define-a-class-in-javascript) question on stackoverflow is closed, to many people's surprise and dismay.

From what I see, the main reason is the title: "What is the best way to (...)" is usually an indicator of a bad question, as "the best way" is just a matter of opinion. However, the question's content is *not* opinion-based. It asks for the syntax of each option, and for advantages & disadvantages of each option -- something that's usually not considered as overly opinion based.

Still, my question remains: how can this question be improved so that it can be reopened? As you can see in the upvotes, number of views and discussion in comments, this is in fact a very popular, useful question.

Comment: Note that the question was posted in 2008, it is still around as it's useful and has historical significance, but it should _not_ be reopened. I think it's closed with the wrong reason as it is IMO "too broad" - you could probably write a small book about the topic if you're going to actually compare the different approaches. Thus to make it on-topic, you would have to significantly reduce its scope, which would invalidate many of the answers. Simply leave it as is.

Answer (score 5):

That question already has 16 answers. It doesn't need to be reopened.

It's not just the title that makes that question opinion-based.

> ... there are at least a couple of ways to go about doing that. What would be the syntax and why would it be done in that way?

The OP is asking for a list of ways to define classes in JavaScript, and the reasoning behind each. Lists are problematic on their own, and the reasoning behind each *is* based on opinion.

Being popular, or having a lot of people complain about a question being closed in the comments is not a good enough reason to reopen a question. That question did manage to generate some good answers, which is why it's only closed and not deleted, but most question that ask for a list never amount to much. Consider the near duplicate question [How can I emulate “classes” in JavaScript? (with or without a third-party library)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/355848/1288). That question is better posed, and did get one good response, but we could delete the rest and little of value would be lost. This is why questions asking for opinions or lists are not up to site standards. Most of them just generate noise. We keep some of the old ones with good answers around to preserve that good content, but we keep them closed to let people know that we don't want any more of them.